# Reliable hover detection with animation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, hover

It seems that jquery hover (and presumably the underlying browser events) cannot be reliably used to keep track of which element the mouse is over when animations are involved, since the events do not fire if an element moves under or away from the mouse (rather than the mouse moving into the element).

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qe3C/2/) for an example of the issue I'm having. If you hover over the div, the state according to the hover tracking events always disagree with reality, at least by the end of the animation.

I haven't tested this outside chrome, but I'm assuming the same behaviour across browsers.

HTML:

```
<div>hover me</div>
<p>state</p>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
div:hover {
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: translateX(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('div').hover(function() {
    $('p').text('over');
}, function() {
    $('p').text('out');
});
```

While the fiddle isn't a realistic example, I'm experiencing this issue in a webpage with animations. The question I have is how do I ensure that my javascript correctly knows the hover state after animations? I'd like to do this without having a global mousemove event to follow the mouse (i.e. so that I can look for the element under the last coordinate at the end of each animation).